# How to define colores in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to customize my colours in this figure:

```
 library(ggplot2);
 col=c("red","black","green","blue","grey","skyblue","darkgreen")
 names(col)=c("2seater","suv","subcompact","midsize","minvan","compa 
ct","pickup")

  ggplot(mpg, aes(x=class, y=hwy, fill=col)) + 
  geom_boxplot(alpha=0.3) +
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error in `geom_boxplot()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `check_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or
the same as the data (234)
✖ Fix the following mappings: `fill`
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.`
```

Comment: Well, it tells you exactly what is wrong "_Aesthetics must be either length 1 or
the same as the data (234)_". Then it tells you how to see exactly where it happens "_Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred._". You should specify which part of these things you are not understanding and what research you did and/or what attempts you made to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `fill` aesthetic with same class and assign col to `values` and the names to `breaks` in `scale_fill_manual` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2);
col=c("red","black","green","blue","grey","skyblue","darkgreen")
names(col)=c("2seater","suv","subcompact","midsize","minvan","compact","pickup")

ggplot(mpg, aes(x=class, y=hwy, fill = class)) + 
  geom_boxplot(alpha=0.3) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = col, breaks = names(col)) +
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, great, can I see the borders of each box plot are still in black. Can we change this to the fill colours?

Comment: I mean the outlines

Comment: Yes you could use the color aesthetic for that!

Comment: you mean like this scale_color_manual(values = col

Comment: Yes and aes(color=class) same like fill!